# Save/Pass/GET event after page reload

Tags: javascript, cordova, events, addeventlistener, window.open

I try to open a cordova-app with custom-url-scheme.

When I use it after triggering an event it works fine like this:

```
<input id="myInput" onkeydown="checkKey(event);"/>

function checkKey(event) {
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        window.open('blablabla'); // call the App
    }
};
```

Unfortunately in my case by pressing the Enter-key, the value has to be checked by a backend system, which then reloads the page.

So I tried this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   window.open('blablabla'); // call the App
}, false);
```

The problem here is that have no active event, so chrome makes a navigation.block an the App cannot be opened.

Is there a way not to lose the event by reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

1. prevent the default behavior on press enter
2. send the value via ajax
3. get the response
4. open the app
5. List item

Conclusion:

1. Problem solved
2. no need for page reload
3. faster end result

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `DOMContentLoaded` event you could just use `ondeviceready` event. In that, on initial page's (index page) `onDeviceReady()` you can do your validations and call the first page of the app after that.

We do this generally for login pages before directing users to main page of the app. For example -

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    //get the value
    //check event through backend system
     window.open('blablabla');  //call the App's first page
}
```

Quoting from `[deviceready][1]` Documentation -

> The deviceready event behaves somewhat differently from others. **Any event handler registered after the deviceready event fires has its callback function called immediately.**